# MVC: Toggle checkbox visibility in modal using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to toggle a series of check box's using a button called toggle. I thought id written the code correctly but when run and I click the button nothing happens, can anyone tell me what Ive missed?

JQuery:

```
 $("toggle").click(function () {
        if ($("[name=checks]:visible").length)
            $("[name=checks]").hide;
        else
            $("[name=checks]").show
    });
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Summary</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h2>Results</h2>
                            <h5>Testing</h5>
                            <span id="printCode"></span><br />

                            <div class="pull-right"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="toggle">Toggle</button> </div>

                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th>Date</th>
                                        <th>Test Type</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>                               
                                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                                    {
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="checks">
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreationDateTime)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AppModeId)
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    }                                                                 
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success"
                                       data-toggle="modal"
                                       data-target="#basicModal3" id="resultsgo">Go!</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save changes</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
$("toggle").click(function () {
```

Write this

```
$("#toggle").click(function () {    //<----use '#' id selector here
```

EDIT :-

```
 $("#toggle").click(function () {
    if ($("[name=checks]").is(":visible"))
        $("[name=checks]").hide();  //<---- use .hide() and not .hide (Use .hide() as a method)
    else
        $("[name=checks]").show();  //<---- use .show() and not .show (Use .show() as a method)
 });
```

EDIT :-

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sp3obx6q/)

Comment: Thanks Kartikeya, silly mistake on my part here. afraid the code still does not hide the checkboxs.

Comment: thanks for the update however it wont hide the check box still. To make it easier Ive copied it into a fiddle just with different id's http://jsfiddle.net/fy2jnv56/:(

Comment: @Baggerz..there was a small mistake you have to use .hide() and not .hide  ..its working see here http://jsfiddle.net/fy2jnv56/1/

Comment: and instead of id use class because id's cant be duplicate..see here http://jsfiddle.net/fy2jnv56/2/

Comment: thank you Kartikeya, ill go try it in my VS project and will give you accepted answer :)

Comment: @Baggerz.. instead of id use class because id's cant be duplicate..see here .... jsfiddle.net/fy2jnv56/2

Answer (score 1):

Try **JQuery Toggle** function to achieve this task:

```
$(function(){
    $("#toggle").click(function () {
        $("[name=checks]").toggle();
    });
});
```

Use `$("#toggle")` in place of `$("toggle")`

Comment: Thanks Hiren for the advice unfortunately Kartikeya beat you too it with the same change, after this change tho the code still doesn't hide the check box.

Comment: @Baggerz - Make sure that you wrote the code with in `$(function(){ //YOUR CODE });` Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("[name=checks]").is(":visible").toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

check this one: 
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z53xL7ps/6/)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checks">
<input type="checkbox" name="checks">
<input type="checkbox" name="checks">
<input type="checkbox" name="checks">
<input type="checkbox" name="checks">
<input type="checkbox" name="checks">
<br>
<button id="testToggle">toggle</button>

$(function() {
    $("#testToggle").on("click", function () {
        $("[name=checks]").toggle();     
    });
});
```